# Built-in for finding the starting positions of a substring in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have written a function to find the starting positions of a substring in a string in Ruby, and from the tests it looks like it is working:

```
def positions(substring, string)
  string
    .chars
    .each_with_index
    .select {|_, index| string[index ... index + substring.length] == substring}
    .map(&:last)
end

p positions("foo", "The foo example: foo and bar and foo") #=> [4, 17, 33]
p positions("ab", "xxxabxxxabxx") #=> [3, 8]
```

I am **not** asking a Code-Review, my question is: Which built-in in Ruby will accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 3):

```
> "The foo example: foo and bar and foo".enum_for(:scan, "foo").map { $~.offset(0)[0] }
=> [4, 17, 33]
```

This is how it works:

`enum_for(:scan, "foo")` creates enumerator using scan("foo") as its map method. Scan yields when substring is found and `$~` is a global variable for last Regex match and scan is using it. `offset(n)` is an array that consists of indexes of first and last elements of n-th match

```
 > "The foo example: foo and bar and foo".match(/foo/).offset(0)
 => [4, 7]
```

Comment: Sorry, your code is wrong, The result must be the starting positions of the substrings.

Comment: @Caridorc  Sorry, but You are wrong. My code is doing good. Just check.

Comment: Correct, sorry I was testing the second snippet, it works.

Comment: And yes, i guess there is no built-in method in Ruby to do this. So You have to choose the most suitable variant. And I guess mine is not the best option since its too complex but still)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`String#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-index) might be more clear, as it is used to get index of substring:

```
def positions(substring, string)
  arr = [];  i = 0
  while(i = string.index(substring, i))
    arr << i; i += 1
  end
  arr
end
```

Comment: So you think that there is no built-in ?